# riak search - json properties are all strings?

Tags: json, riak

I'm storing json docs in riak search, for example:

```
{
  boolean: true,
  number: 1.234,
  string: "Gretchen"
}
```

However, when querying for them (riak search), I notice the fields returned by the query are all strings:

```
{
  boolean: "true",
  number: "1.234",
  string: "Gretchen"
}
```

This makes the query results useless for binding to objects, unless I then sequentially retrieve each doc again via their key.  Is this possible to get the correctly typed fields returned?    E.g. Couch+lucene does this correctly and makes it very useful for querying + binding.

Comment: What content type are you storing the documents under?

Comment: application/json, I'm querying via REST.  If this works for you, could you please post how you are querying?  I'm getting thoroughly confused between the various options: solr/mapreduce/secondary indices/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds it's not possible, you need to use map reduce for this.  From Sean at Basho:

> "What a search query returns to you is the "index document", or the
>   result of transforming the input before adding it to the search
>   indexes; this also means that deeply nested fields will be flattened.
>   If you want the original, you can use MapReduce to retrieve the
>   documents resulting from a search query."